# Using FsCheck.Xunit in C#, how do I clean up/tear down after all tests have been executed?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, fscheck, teardown

I am using [FsCheck](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/) - specifically the **FsCheck.Xunit** package - in my C# code. I want to run some setup before my tests execute and some cleanup/teardown code after my tests have all run.

NUnit has a **[CleanUp]** attribute; Xunit uses *Dispose* to clean up. In some frameworks I think it's called **[TearDown]**. Is there anything of this sort in FsCheck.Xunit?

When I rewrote one Xunit test class to use FsCheck, I could see that my *Dispose* method no longer got executed.

In the [documentation](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/reference/index.html) there is something called "TearDown", but it is completely opaque to me how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in FsCheck.Xunit. Can you open an issue?

Comment: The TearDown is for state machine based testing; it's not meant to be used as a general teardown functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Issue reported: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/514